# How to retrieve sql results containing ' char

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I am using select statement to retrieve certain data from sqlite. The result contains ' char which results error when selecting data. How can I ignore it?

Below is my sql statement:

```
string query = string.Format("select * from TableA where [Col]='{0}'",suraTName) 

Statement: select * from TableA where [Col]='An-Naazi'aat'
```

How to ignore ' char and have the correct the result?

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't do it like this. Use parameterized SQL, it will also fix your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a parameterized query like this

```
string query = "select * from TableA where [Col]=@colValue";
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@colValue", suraTName);
```

In this way the job to correctly quote your value is passed to the SQLite provider that knows better. Also, there is no possibility of [Sql Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

Of course this is possible if you are using a ADO.NET provider like the one from [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki), if you are using other systems to retrieve your data, I can only suggest to double the single quote in your query

```
suraTName = suraTName.Replace("'", "''");
string query = string.Format("select * from TableA where [Col]='{0}'",suraTName);
```

But it is very risky option

Comment: Thanks, There is no Parameters in sqlite (cmd.Parameters)

Comment: Are you sure? What version or what provider are you using, because here http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/artifact/dad394fdf2af9b24 seems that the Parameters collection is available being a class derived by DbCommand.

Comment: Oh, I am not using System.Data.Sqite (Where this comes from). I am using SQLite only.

Comment: Then I can only suggest to try to double your single quote. But it is very risky

Comment: I may not be able to user that, Just a question: Am I using the wrong dll? Though I installed SqliteX86

Comment: It is not clear to me how do you interact with the SQLite database without a ADO.NET provider (SQLiteConnection, SQLiteCommand, SQLiteDataReader etc.). I strongly suggest to use an ADO.NET provider to interact with the database

Comment: Oh I didn't mention, I am using sqlite in windows phone8 and there is no such in windows phone8. You need to add the c++ wrapper class to extend using sqlite database. (http://blog.rajenki.com/2013/01/sqlite-on-windows-8-and-windows-phone-8/)

Comment: Did you try the workaround with the Replace call? Also, adding the tag WinPhone could help to get attention from more experts on the subject

Comment: Thanks, I sorted it out by passing ID instead of file name. That was the easiest solution i could follow.

Comment: Yes, rule #1 - Keep It Simple and Stupid - bye